# Customize the sidebar, fortyseconds CV

Tags: templates, cv, sidebar

I would like to put a References section in the sidebar of my CV, something like the first picture but with the icons from the second. The first picture layout is computed from a template I found online that can't be adapted to my code.

I tried to do something but it didn't work out, in fact the second piture comes from my code. I used the memberships section bc it is the only solution I found to put the icons I want. The problem is that the emails and phone numbers below the names go too much to the left. I hope that it is clear, do you have any suggestions on how to change my code? Thanks

```
\profilesection{References}
    \begin{memberships}
        \membership[3em]{pics/woman.png}{Pinco Pallo}
        \membership[3em]{pics/man.png}{Ezio Birro}{ezio.birro@ggg.it}
    \end{memberships}
```

Anyhow, I'm using the CV from this template
https://es.overleaf.com/articles/anirban-bhattacharyas-resume/cmnzzrwvkcsw where .tex file is the Main one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was defined a new command `\xref[<width of the image>]{<image file>}{<data>}` with the one optional parameter and two mandatory.

Add before `\begin{document}`

```
%*************************************************************
\newcommand{\xref}[3][4em]{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \includegraphics[align=c,width=#1]{#2}\hspace*{1em}\parbox{\linewidth-#1-1.5em}{#3} \par
}
%************************************************************
```

and include

```
\profilesection{References}
    \xref[5em]{example-image-a}{Pinco Pallo \\ +91 8902391067}
    \xref[5em]{example-image-b}{Ezio Birro \\ ezio.birro@ggg.it}
    \xref[5em]{example-image-c}{Mauro Rondizone \\ Via Apia Antica 31, \\ Rome, Italy}
```

in the group `\addtofrontsidebar{... }` in the place you want to appear.

[image: a]

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked